# How to set wallpaper to whole screen of device in android

Tags: android, image, fullscreen, wallpaper

I am using set as wallpaper in my android app. But when I set image as wallpaper its zoom upto some extent on device. I want when I set image as wallpaper. This fit on every screen device. I am using DisplayMetrices but its not working perfect.

Code-

```
   public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {

    int position, width, height;
    LinearLayout full;
    Button btn;
    Context context;
    DisplayMetrics metrics;

    public Integer[] mThumbId = {
                R.drawable.kri1, R.drawable.kri2,
                R.drawable.kri3, R.drawable.kri4,
                R.drawable.kri5, R.drawable.kri6,
                R.drawable.kri7, R.drawable.kri8,
                R.drawable.kri9
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

        // get intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Selected image id
        position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");        
        full = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.full);
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        changeBackground();
        metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        width = metrics.widthPixels;
        height = metrics.heightPixels;
        btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                myWallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
                myWallpaperManager.setResource(mThumbId[position]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }});
        ActivitySwipeDetector activitySwipeDetector = new ActivitySwipeDetector(this);
        full.setOnTouchListener(activitySwipeDetector);
    }

    private void changeBackground(){
        full.setBackgroundResource(mThumbId[position]);
   }

    public class ActivitySwipeDetector implements View.OnTouchListener {

        static final String logTag = "ActivitySwipeDetector";
        static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 100;
        private float downX, upX;
        Activity activity;

        public ActivitySwipeDetector(Activity activity){
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        public void onRightToLeftSwipe(){
            Log.i(logTag, "RightToLeftSwipe!");
            if(position < mThumbId.length - 1){
                position++;
                 changeBackground();
            }
    }

        public void onLeftToRightSwipe(){
            Log.i(logTag, "LeftToRightSwipe!");
            if(position > 0){
                position--;
                changeBackground();
           }
        }

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    downX = event.getX();
                    return true;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    upX = event.getX();

                    float deltaX = downX - upX;

                    // swipe horizontal?
                    if(Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE){
                        // left or right
                        if(deltaX < 0) { this.onLeftToRightSwipe(); return true; }
                        if(deltaX > 0) { this.onRightToLeftSwipe(); return true; }
                    }
                    else {
                            Log.i(logTag, "Swipe was only " + Math.abs(deltaX) + " long, need at least " + MIN_DISTANCE);
                            return false; // We don't consume the event
                    }


                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use different size imazes so that they can support all the screens.

Comment: I dont want to use different size images. Because I dont want size of my app too big.

Comment: ohk...so u can use a big size image and use resolution code for different resolutions using display metrics...

Comment: I have already tried but its not working.

Comment: you r getting error on context,use getapplicationcontext or this in place of context...

Comment: @krishna still image zoom upto some extent.

Comment: what is the size of ur image??

Comment: in which resolutions it is having a zooming effect??

Comment: Can you post pictures of how it looks?

Answer (score 2):

Try this-

```
Bitmap bmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getResources().openRawResource(mThumb[position]));
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int height = metrics.heightPixels; 
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
Bitmap yourbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmap, width, height, true); 
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this); 
try {
  wallpaperManager.setBitmap(yourbitmap);
  } catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i'm using this library in my app
it works and it's easy

[CropImage](https://github.com/biokys/cropimage)

it's open source so you can edit the library as you like

have fun

Comment: I don't want to crop image.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need a `Image` Scaling Algorithm that maintains the image Aspect Ratio,
Store the best image you have in your drawable folder and let this `Algorithm` scale down the best image to fit the device's `Height` & `Width`, maintaining the aspect ratio of the orignal Image.

```
 Bitmap scaleDownLargeImageWithAspectRatio(Bitmap image)
            {
                int imaheVerticalAspectRatio,imageHorizontalAspectRatio;
                float bestFitScalingFactor=0;
                float percesionValue=(float) 0.2;

                //getAspect Ratio of Image
                int imageHeight=(int) (Math.ceil((double) image.getHeight()/100)*100);
                int imageWidth=(int) (Math.ceil((double) image.getWidth()/100)*100);
                int GCD=BigInteger.valueOf(imageHeight).gcd(BigInteger.valueOf(imageWidth)).intValue();
                imaheVerticalAspectRatio=imageHeight/GCD;
                imageHorizontalAspectRatio=imageWidth/GCD;
                Log.i("scaleDownLargeImageWIthAspectRatio","Image Dimensions(W:H): "+imageWidth+":"+imageHeight);
                Log.i("scaleDownLargeImageWIthAspectRatio","Image AspectRatio(W:H): "+imageHorizontalAspectRatio+":"+imaheVerticalAspectRatio);

                //getContainer Dimensions
                int displayWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
                int displayHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
               //I wanted to show the image to fit the entire device, as a best case. So my ccontainer dimensions were displayWidth & displayHeight. For your case, you will need to fetch container dimensions at run time or you can pass static values to these two parameters 

                int leftMargin = 0;
                int rightMargin = 0;
                int topMargin = 0;
                int bottomMargin = 0;
                int containerWidth = displayWidth - (leftMargin + rightMargin);
                int containerHeight = displayHeight - (topMargin + bottomMargin);
                Log.i("scaleDownLargeImageWIthAspectRatio","Container dimensions(W:H): "+containerWidth+":"+containerHeight);

                //iterate to get bestFitScaleFactor per constraints
                while((imageHorizontalAspectRatio*bestFitScalingFactor <= containerWidth) && 
                        (imaheVerticalAspectRatio*bestFitScalingFactor<= containerHeight))
                {
                    bestFitScalingFactor+=percesionValue;
                }

                //return bestFit bitmap
                int bestFitHeight=(int) (imaheVerticalAspectRatio*bestFitScalingFactor);
                int bestFitWidth=(int) (imageHorizontalAspectRatio*bestFitScalingFactor);
                Log.i("scaleDownLargeImageWIthAspectRatio","bestFitScalingFactor: "+bestFitScalingFactor);
                Log.i("scaleDownLargeImageWIthAspectRatio","bestFitOutPutDimesions(W:H): "+bestFitWidth+":"+bestFitHeight);
                image=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, bestFitWidth,bestFitHeight, true);

                //Position the bitmap centre of the container
                int leftPadding=(containerWidth-image.getWidth())/2;
                int topPadding=(containerHeight-image.getHeight())/2;
                Bitmap backDrop=Bitmap.createBitmap(containerWidth, containerHeight, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
                Canvas can = new Canvas(backDrop);
                can.drawBitmap(image, leftPadding, topPadding, null);

                return backDrop;
            }


private void changeBackground()
    {
        Drawable inputDrawable = mThumbId[position];
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)inputDrawable).getBitmap();
        bitmap = scaleDownLargeImageWithAspectRatio(bitmap);
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Drawable outDrawable=new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);  
        full.setBackground(outDrawable);
    }
```

Comment: Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)mThumbId[position]).getBitmap(); on this line. cannot cast bitmap to integer error.

Comment: I have added  changeBackground(), at the bottom of my answer.
Please check and provide feedback.

Comment: I am setting wallpaper on button click dont you think I have to include any code in button onClick.

Comment: Mate,
make a call to the function changeBackground() in the button's onClick method.

Answer (score 0):

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```